# OpenOffice API - Calc - filterring questions

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have a XLS file which I can open via API

http://www.openoffice.org/api/basic/man/tutorial/tutorial.pdf

In this XLS file I have sheet with about 10 columns. Each of this columns have alredy setup filters.

My question are related to do this followed things **via API**:

1. Is it possible to find out if for specific column filter exist or not ?
2. Is it possible to get list of possible option for specific column/filter ?
3. Is it possible to check which option are choosen ?
4. Is it possible to change option  for specific column/filter ?
5. Is it possible to check what region/range is currently filtered (rows list) ?
6. Is it possible to select filtered region (rows list + header) ?

I do not need to get ready to use solution.
**Just please point me to the right/proper API function** and I read their documentation, and when I solve me problems I will be happy to share my solution, and discuss about it.

Comment: For now I found this: [link](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/169169/calc-basic-access-filtered-data-from-macro-code/)

Comment: hmm... nobody ??
I'm working on: 
[link](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Advanced_filters) and [link](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=33542) and here [link](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XSheetFilterDescriptor2.html) will post my solution ... when I finish